# WinUI 3 Circle Button needs to keep hover animation

Tags: xaml, button, hover, background-color, winui-3

In WinUI 3 XAML, I have made a circle button with an icon at its center. Everything is good except that when I hover the mouse the color does not change in comparison with a simple button.

```
<Button Width="80" Height="80">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="Green">
                </Ellipse>
                <FontIcon FontSize="16" Glyph="&#xE8E5;" />
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

How to restore the hover animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override the `ControlTemplate` you also override, in this case remove, the `VisualStates`. So if you need the default behavior for

- PointerOver
- Pressed
- Disabled

you need to add `VisualStates` for each of them.

It should be something like this:

```xml
<Button
    Width="80"
    Height="80"
    Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                <Ellipse
                    x:Name="EllipseBase"
                    Fill="Green" />
                <FontIcon
                    x:Name="FontIconContent"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Glyph="&#xE8E5;" />
                <ContentPresenter
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseBase"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                        KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="MediumSeaGreen" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseBase"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                        KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="ForestGreen" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="FontIconContent"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                        KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseBase"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                        KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="DarkOliveGreen" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="FontIconContent"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                        KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Note that I made some changes from the *DefaultButtonStyle*.
For example, instead of targeting the `ContentPresenter`'s `Background` property, I'm targeting the `Ellipse`'s `Fille` property.

**UPDATE**

If you want to separate the template XAML to another file, you need to create a Style like this:

*NOTE*

You need to add the "Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" namespace due to this known issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6648

**Buttons.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style
        x:Key="AwesomeButtonStyle"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
        TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                        <Ellipse
                            x:Name="EllipseBase"
                            Fill="Green" />
                        <FontIcon
                            x:Name="FontIconContent"
                            FontSize="16"
                            Glyph="&#xE8E5;" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseBase"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="MediumSeaGreen" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseBase"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="ForestGreen" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FontIconContent"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseBase"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="DarkOliveGreen" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FontIconContent"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Buttons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!--  Other app resources here  -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And apply the *AwesomeButtonStyle* like this:

```xml
<Button
    Style="{StaticResource AwesomeButtonStyle}"
    Width="80"
    Height="80"
    Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Template />
</Button>
```

Comment: Is there is a way or a good practice to place these definitions in another place? A static resource, a different file for template definition? Just so the Page's XAML code is more readable.

Comment: You can place your Styles as Page.Resources or Grid.Resources in the same Page, or in App.xaml or even create a file for resources like [this](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/PhotoOrganizer/tree/main/PhotoOrganizerApp/Styles).

Comment: I have those style files from scaffolding with Template Studio, but I don't know the exact syntax to reference VisualState or ControlTemplate from style file to my page xaml. Can you give me some indications? Thank you!

Comment: Updated my answer. Since your project is based on the TemplateStudio, you might want to put **Buttons.xaml** in the **Styles** folder.